# neon library authentication with ip instead of host

Tags: c++, authentication

Im using neon library and I want to authenticate to a server without hostname, just with using ip address. I can use ip address for session creation

`ne_session_create(scheme, ip, port);`

and I need to use the ip address in login parameters instead of hostname

`loginParams = LoginParams(user, pass, host);`

but using ip address there fails in authentication

`ne_set_server_auth(mSession, WebdavClient::setLogin, &loginParams);`

Is there a way in neon library to use an ip address for authentication when there is no hostname ?

Comment: "neon" tag is about the Arm NEON SIMD instruction set, so not relevant to this question.

Comment: @solidpixel Im writing about neon library, so please read it first. Not about instruction set. Simply googling it, first result is the library: https://notroj.github.io/neon/

Comment: Sure, but the "neon" tag you used is for the instruction set. I removed it (the comment was just explaining the tag removal - the question is fine).